# Azure Service Bus JS SDK - mix of classes and interfaces

Tags: c#, typescript, azure, azureservicebus

I'm starting to work with the Azure Service Bus Javascript SDK for a Typescript project and I'm curious about why certain concepts are classes in the C# SDK but interfaces in the JS SDK?

Example: ServiceBusClientOptions
C# documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet

JS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusclientoptions?view=azure-node-latest

I've found I can pass regular JSON objects into these interfaces, which feels easy, but potentially sloppy. The benefit I see is that these can be read in from a JSON config file easily.
`{ retryOptions: {maxRetries: 10}}`

I am using Typescript so I could also add classes that implement these interface types. Thoughts?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking. Are you asking why did the SDK authors use interfaces in the JavaScript SDK instead of classes? That seems like something only the authors could answer definitively, but in short, it is typical practice to represent objects _without functionality_ as interfaces in Typescript, and it is typical to represent _functionality_ as interfaces in C#, whereas concrete _objects_ are expressed as classes/structs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: With respect to the .NET client library, the Azure SDKs have a goal of strict backwards compatibility with a very high bar for any breaking changes.  The use of an interface in .NET makes evolving over time difficult; any change to the public API surface represented by an interface becomes a breaking change for anyone who has already implemented it - including when we want to add new members.  Default interface implementation helps but they're not supported in all of the frameworks that we target.  Open classes with virtual members can still be mocked and do not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks @JesseSquire, that does help answer my question about why classes were chosen for the .NET library.